WebSocket Connection Failing with "WebSocket protocol error" in Socket.io
I'm working on a WebSocket server using socket.io with Node.js and getting a connection issue. I keep getting the error WebSocketError: WebSocket protocol error when I try to connect using websocatand my own frontend
here is my code
ws.ts:

import { Server, Socket } from "socket.io";
import { Server as HttpServer } from "http";
import { saveToS3 } from "./aws";
import { fetchDir, fetchFileContent, saveFile } from "./fs";
import { TerminalManager } from "./pty";

const terminalManager = new TerminalManager();

export function initWs(httpServer: HttpServer) {
    const io = new Server(httpServer, {
        cors: {
            origin: "*", // Allow all origins for testing, restrict in production
            methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        },
    });

    io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
        console.log("WebSocket connection established");
        
        const host = socket.handshake.headers.host;
        console.log(`host is ${host}`);
        
        // Split the host by '.' and take the first part as replId
        const replId = host?.split('.')[0];

        if (!replId) {
            socket.disconnect();
            terminalManager.clear(socket.id);
            return;
        }

        socket.emit("loaded", {
            rootContent: await fetchDir("/workspace", "")
        });

        initHandlers(socket, replId);
    });
}

function initHandlers(socket: Socket, replId: string) {
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("Client disconnected");
    });

    socket.on("fetchDir", async (dir: string, callback) => {
        const dirPath = `/workspace/${dir}`;
        const contents = await fetchDir(dirPath, dir);
        callback(contents);
    });

    socket.on("fetchContent", async ({ path: filePath }: { path: string }, callback) => {
        const fullPath = `/workspace/${filePath}`;
        const data = await fetchFileContent(fullPath);
        callback(data);
    });

    socket.on("updateContent", async ({ path: filePath, content }: { path: string, content: string }) => {
        const fullPath =  `/workspace/${filePath}`;
        await saveFile(fullPath, content);
        await saveToS3(`code/${replId}`, filePath, content);
    });

    socket.on("requestTerminal", async () => {
        terminalManager.createPty(socket.id, replId, (data, id) => {
            socket.emit('terminal', {
                data: Buffer.from(data,"utf-8")
            });
        });
    });
    
    socket.on("terminalData", async ({ data }: { data: string, terminalId: number }) => {
        terminalManager.write(socket.id, data);
    });
}

My index.ts:
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import express from "express";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { initWs } from "./ws";
import cors from "cors";

// Load environment variables
dotenv.config();

const app = express();

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors());

// Create HTTP server
const httpServer = createServer(app);

// Initialize WebSocket
initWs(httpServer);

// Add a test route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Server is running!');
});

// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

Here is how i test with websocat
I’m using websocat to connect:
websocat ws://localhost:3001

I also tried a curl:
  curl -i -N \
    -H "Connection: Upgrade" \
    -H "Upgrade: websocket" \
    -H "Host: localhost:3001" \
    -H "Origin: http://localhost:3001" \
    -H "Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==" \
    -H "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" \
    http://localhost:3001


I want the WebSocket server to make a connection successfully, allowing me to send and receive messages.
When I run websocat, I get the following error:

websocat: WebSocketError: WebSocket protocol error

The raw curl command returns:
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
The server logs confirm that the server is running and listening on port 3001:
  Server is listening on port 3001
Troubleshooting Steps Taken

Server is listening on port 3001.
Ensured that CORS settings are configured to allow connections from any origin.


    const io = new Server(httpServer, {
        cors: {
            origin: "*",
            methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        },
        transports: ['websocket'], // Force WebSocket only
    });
    
    Checked for firewall issues that might block the WebSocket connection.


What  is causing the WebSocket protocol error, and how can I make a WebSocket connection to my server?

Do you have any logs on the server side?
